# All https sites are deemed unsafe

Tags: 14.04, ssl, https

I have installed a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 and updated it. But SSL certicates for https sites (even google.com) are not installed in Chromium and Firefox. So the brwoser thinks these sites are unasfe.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is your time correct? And is ca-certificates installed?

Comment: I'll check‌‌‌‌‌.

Comment: I doubt that these certificates are not installed since they come with the browser and are independent of ca-certificates. Check if you are behind some SSL firewall or similar device which does SSL interception.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: After fresh Ubuntu, kde-full and chromium browser are installed.

Comment: Again, check that there are no SSL intercepting middleboxes and that your time is correct like suggested by @ethanbmnz. If still in doubt post the details of the certificate chain as seen by the browser.

Comment: @ethanbmnz Yes I think it was time and date problem which was solved. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the solution was to change the date and time to the correct values.

If anyone else is having the same issue as the question asker, and their date and time is correct, try installing `ca-certificates`